# geom_line with 10,000 groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing 10,000 simulations of a varible and I want to plot each simulation in a single plot. I'm not being able of doing a nice plot with geom_line because it appears I have a lot of groups.

Here is a reproducible example and the plot I'm making.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfan)
library(gridExtra)
library(stringr)
library(scales)

#Create a dataframe 
month <- 1:120 
price_a <- 5000 
demand <- 10
data <- data.frame(month, price_a, demand)

#Create 100 simulations to project price_a and demand for the future
simulations <- 10000
intervalo <- seq_len(120)
set.seed(96)
lista_meses <- lapply(setNames(intervalo, paste0("data", intervalo)), function(i) {
  cbind(
    data[rep(i, simulations),],
    growth_pricea = as.numeric(runif(simulations, min = -0.02, max = 0.05)),
    growth_demand = as.numeric(runif(simulations, min = -0.03, max = 0.03)),
    revenue = demand*price_a
  )
})

#Calculate the growth of each variable and revenue
for (i in 2:length(lista_meses)){
  lista_meses[[i]][["price_a"]] <- lista_meses[[i-1]][["price_a"]]*(1+lista_meses[[i]][["growth_pricea"]])
  lista_meses[[i]][["demand"]] <- lista_meses[[i-1]][["demand"]]*(1+lista_meses[[i]][["growth_demand"]])
  lista_meses[[i]][["revenue"]] <- lista_meses[[i]][["price_a"]]*lista_meses[[i]][["demand"]]
}

#Extract revenue columns from all dataframes in list
time <- 1:120 #10 years. 

extract_column <- lapply(lista_meses, function(x) x["revenue"]) 

fandataq <- do.call("cbind", extract_column) 
mandataq <- as.matrix.data.frame(fandataq)
pdataq <- data.frame(x=time, t(fandataq)) %>% gather(key=sim, value=y, -x)


#Plotting ALL SIMULATIONS
ggplot(pdataq, aes(x=x, y= y, group = sim, colour = sim)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE)
```

This is the plot I'm getting, I don't why that area is completely pink when it should be of a lot of colours and a lot of lines. Does anybody knows how can I solve this? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: With that many groups, it's not helpful to have the different colors. I'd recommend removing the color mapping, but add `alpha = 0.1` to the `geom_line` call.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, that must be the problem. Do you think is there a way I can use like 4-5 different colors and achieve a nice graph? Or the only way is to have just one color?

Comment: What would the different colour add?  No way are you actually following an individual line with it...

Comment: Just to show in a more clear way that I'm presenting multiple lines. I saw something like that in Python and believed that it could be achieved in R as well.

Comment: Even just using one color I still get that full-colored area like if I were using geom_fan. Any idea of how to not have that area but a lot of lines?

Comment: The transparency is set with `alpha` as I mentioned. That should help. But it's a lot of lines so you might have to set it super low. Are you sure you need to see all 10k lines at once? I don't think it will be easy to visualize that many individual lines at once. I'm assuming what you care about is some descriptive statistics (e.g. range, IQR, med) right? Why not calculate those and then plot them to summarize the population?

Comment: Ok, no problem! I'll set alpha as low as possible and work with that. Thanks again!